# How to prove that an infinite series does not converge to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinity

I am now considering the following infinite series.

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{1}{j(j+1)} \left\{\exp\left(\frac{2 \pi i}{n} \right)\right\}^{j} $$

Here, $n \geq 2$ is a natural number and $i$ is imaginary unit.

We know that this infinite series converges.
How can we prove that the convergence value of this infinite series is not $0$ ?
(It is not always necessary to find the limit value. Since convergence is guaranteed, it is sufficient to show that it does not converge to $0$.)

I could show in the case of $n=2$ by using partial fractional decomposition

However, in other cases, I am having trouble calculating the specifics as described above.

Comment: What is being raised to the $j$th power? Because in the way I would most naturally interpret that, there is a subsequence of exponentially growing terms every $j$ a multiple of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ By considering the series

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{z^j}{j(j+1)}$$ and using partial fraction decomposition, we obtain that your series is equal to

$$1 - \operatorname{Log}\left(1-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)\right) + \exp\left(-\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)\operatorname{Log}\left(1-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)\right)$$

Comment: @DominikS you make a good point, I have changed every reference of log to the principal branch.